# Issue with running optaplanner code via mvn integration-test goal

Tags: maven, config, solver, optaplanner

I have an application that uses Optaplanner to generate a plan. When I write an Integration test and invoke the test from the terminal's command line using mvn integration-test, optaplanner throws an exception. The exception is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed" caused by "at org.optaplanner.core.config.domain.ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.buildSolutionDescriptor(ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.java:84)".

The production code works and my hunch is that it is not able to find the solver config resource using this path :

```
solverFactoryBase = SolverFactory
                .createFromXmlResource("solver/solverConfig-minDistanceTimeToProcess.xml");
```

This is the exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:686)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$200(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.hasNext(ZipFile.java:508)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.hasMoreElements(ZipFile.java:503)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.hasNext(JarFile.java:253)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.hasMoreElements(JarFile.java:262)
    at org.reflections.vfs.ZipDir$1$1.computeNext(ZipDir.java:30)
    at org.reflections.vfs.ZipDir$1$1.computeNext(ZipDir.java:26)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:243)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:202)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:123)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.domain.ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.buildSolutionDescriptor(ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.java:84)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolutionDescriptor(SolverConfig.java:341)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:251)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:61)
    at com.brc.planner.app.UavRoutePlanner.callSolver(UavRoutePlanner.java:190)
    at com.brc.planner.app.UavRoutePlanner.lambda$createReceive$0(UavRoutePlanner.java:138)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:180)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Wanted to add some env details - Optaplanner (v 7.13), junit 5, maven 3.6, failsafe plugin (v 2.22.0)

Comment: Don't classpath resources normally start with "/"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse `createFromXmlResource()` with `createFromXmlFile()`.

`createFromXmlResource()` expects a classpath resource, which is normally in a namespace (= java package), such as `"/org/foo/barSolverConfig.xml"` to avoid trouble when it gets uber-jarred or zipped.